# Make a Video with Images

Tags: php, linux, video

I want to allow users to upload a bunch of images and arrange it in a particular order and create a video of the same.

Is there some script or tool that i need to install on my server that i can use to achieve the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also [PHP API](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/) for ffmpeg

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can [make a video from an image sequence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence) with FFmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ffmpeg.org](http://ffmpeg.org/), there is sample tutorial [tutorial](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

Answer (score 1):

If gif-videos are enough, this is also possible using ImageMagick. The details can be looked up [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/).